Binomial coefficient inequality ${n+x \choose x} > {{m+q-x} \choose q-x}$
Let $m,n,q$ be positive integers and $0\leq x\leq q$ where $x$ is an integer.
When does the inequality
$$
{n +x \choose x} > {{m+q-x} \choose q-x}
$$
hold?
Using the Hockey-Stick identity,
$$
{n+x \choose x} = \sum_{k=0}^x {k+n-1 \choose k} \text{ and } {m+q-x \choose q-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{q-x} {k+m-1 \choose k}.
$$
It is clear for $n \geq m$ that the inequality holds for $x > \frac{1}{2}q$.
Now I'm stuck from this point onwards.

It is clear that any non-negative integer value of $x$ is possible.
The choice of $x$ puts a constraint on $q$, namely, $q \geq x$,
in addition to the constraint that $q$ is a positive integer,
but the only constraints on $m$ and $n$ remain that they must be positive integers.
Let
\begin{align}
r &= n + x, \\
s &= m+q-x, \\
t &= q - x.
\end{align}
Then $t$ can be any non-negative integer (except that $x$ and $t$ cannot both be zero) and $r$ and $s$ can be any integers such that $r > x$ and $s > t$.
Then $\dbinom{n + x}{x} = \dbinom{r}{x}$ and  $\dbinom{m+q-x}{q-x} = \dbinom{s}{t}$,
where $r,s,t,x$ are integers, $r > x \geq 0$, and $s > t \geq 0$.
Essentially, then, your question is equivalent to the most general question of when $\dbinom rx > \dbinom st$ for non-negative integers
except that you have eliminated the relatively trivial cases where $r = x$, $s = t$,
or $x = t = 0$.
You can certainly find a number of other conditions that will satisfy your inequality -- it may help to recall that $\dbinom ab = \dbinom a{a - b}$ --
but I don't think you'll find a complete set of conditions that will cover all cases where the inequality is satisfied.
